# Unable to get data from hdf file in python

Tags: python, hdf5, hdf

I have two hdf files, hdf4 and hdf5. In both cases, I am able to load the files in python using respective libraries (pyhdf and h5py). But inside the files, I can only read the data fields' name, size, and other parameters. The datasets are coming in tuples. I am unable to extract the actual data. Below is the code I am using. I was previously using MATLAB where both worked fine. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import os
import h5py as hp
import numpy as np
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC  

path=r'C:\Users\Sky\Desktop'
os.chdir(path)

f1=hp.File('TPR7_uw1_00539.19980101.011127_SAS.hdf')
ds1=f1.keys()

f2=SD('era5_2020_4_17_18.00_23.88_91.24.HDF')
ds2=f2.datasets()
T=ds2["T"] # Temperature
```

dataset output:
[image: dataset output]

Comment: What is the output of your code?  You haven't showed us how it fails.

Comment: Check the attached image. It shows the field names but not data

Comment: In matlab i can view the data inside the file but here only the field names not the actual data

Comment: You still have not show how it fails. Where do you get a "none " or "KeyError" or something that you do not expect ?

Comment: The image seems to show both keys and values.  What is it SUPPOSED to look like?

Comment: There is the issue. Only the key names are showing not the values associated with it. Each parameter is an array of length 28. The length of the array is showing not the elements of the array. Am I able to make problem clear??

Comment: Not sure about HDF4 without looking it up but h5py datasets act like proxies for numpy arrays. If you want to read the data, use the pattern `file["dataset"][:]` or whatever slice you want, e.g. `file["dataset"][start:end]`

Comment: Thank you @Homer512. Now I can read the content inside the file.